# Alamofire.request does not map with custom object

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I was trying to create a sample app in swift that maps with alamofire with alamofire object mapper. The whole idea of this sample app is to map json response with custom model that I make. But when I try to loop the object list, it says that custom object is not compatible and its a dictionary.

Here is my network layer code

```
// MARK: retrieve country list
func retrieveCountryList(completion: @escaping (_ result: NSArray) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").
responseJSON{(response: DataResponse<Any>) in
            let result = response.result.value;
            let resultsArray = result as! NSArray
            completion(resultsArray)
      }
 }
```

and model

```
class Country : Mappable {

    var name:String?
    var capital:String?

    required init(map : Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        capital <- map["capital"]
    }
}
```

It seems that the response is doesn't directly maps with model. what might be the issue ?

alamofire version  4.3

Comment: use `responseObject` instead of `responseString`

Comment: ResponseObject . Doesn not allow in almofire latest one

Answer (score 0):

- You first need to install "AlamofireObjectMapper" .
- For which you should add into your project by including "pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'" followed by command "pod install" .
- Now in your API call class "import AlamofireObjectMapper" and try typing ".responseObject" you'll get it.